# How to add my own message when debugQuery is set to on in SOLR

Tags: solr

I implemented my own QParserPlugin and am wondering how I could add my own message when debugQuery parameter is set to "on"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called addDebugInfo:

public void addDebugInfo(NamedList debugInfo)

You can override this to add your own message but make sure to call super.addDebugInfo.